# How to change transparency of block terminal cursor?

Tags: terminal, cursor

I really like using block type cursors, but the one in the default terminal isn't transparent, so it obscures the character that is selected.

Is there a way to make it transparent or maybe make it so the colour of the selected character is inverted, so it can be seen through the cursor.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot, System Version, Terminal Profile? Because my cursor is displayed behind the character (background color is changed).

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/71oLAlS.png) is a screenshot of my terminal. The character under the cursor is 'C', but you can't see it. I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73) and I'm using a Monokai terminal profile I downloaded, but I checked also with the Homebrew profile and the cursor still obscures the character it is on.

Comment: OK I get it, I have the same on my homebrew profile - it's because the cursor is the same color as the text. So far I was not able to find the solution to change the text color underneath the cursor. Workaround is to set the transparency of the cursor around 60%

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek How do you set the transparency of the cursor?

Comment: @Bart The easiest way to do it is: go to Terminal preferences, select your profile, under text there's a "cursor" color picker. Select your desired color and change it's transparency/opacity in that color picker.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek thanks for the reply! However, I want/need to do it via my .bashrc script.  This is how I'm setting it now at the end of my .bashrc file:

printf '\e[2 q\e]12;yellow\a'

wondering if you know of a way to sneak transparency/opacity in to that little beauty.